# Constructor delegation with std::array<>

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list, stdarray

I have a class which receives a `std::array` in the constructor. For the life of me I can't write a correct and simple delegation from `std::initializer_list` - only the awkward lambda which I have commented out. Can someone show me a clean and sensible way without ad-hoc code?

```
#include <array>

class foo
{
  std::array<int,5> t_;
  
public:
  
  foo(): foo{{}}
  { }
  
  foo(std::initializer_list<int> il = {}): foo{ std::array<int,5>(il) }
      // foo { [il]() {
      //   std::array<int,5> tmp;
      //   std::size_t i = 0;
      //   for (auto ile: il)
      //     if (i >= tmp.size()) break;
      //     else tmp[i++]=ile;
      //   return tmp;
      // }()}
  { }
                          
  foo(std::array<int,5> t): t_(t)
  { }
};
```

This gives:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra   -c -o t.o t.cpp
t.cpp: In constructor 'foo::foo(std::initializer_list<int>)':
t.cpp:12:69: error: no matching function for call to 'std::array<int, 5>::array(std::initializer_list<int>&)'
   12 |   foo(std::initializer_list<int> il = {}): foo{ std::array<int,5>(il) }
      |                                                                     ^
In file included from t.cpp:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/c++/array:94:12: note: candidate: 'std::array<int, 5>::array()'
   94 |     struct array
      |            ^~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/c++/array:94:12: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/c++/array:94:12: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::array<int, 5>::array(const std::array<int, 5>&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/c++/array:94:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::initializer_list<int>' to 'const std::array<int, 5>&'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/c++/array:94:12: note: candidate: 'constexpr std::array<int, 5>::array(std::array<int, 5>&&)'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/include/c++/array:94:12: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::initializer_list<int>' to 'std::array<int, 5>&&'
t.cpp:12:71: error: no matching function for call to 'foo::foo(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)'
   12 |   foo(std::initializer_list<int> il = {}): foo{ std::array<int,5>(il) }
      |                                                                       ^
t.cpp:23:3: note: candidate: 'foo::foo(std::array<int, 5>)'
   23 |   foo(std::array<int,5> t): t_(t)
      |   ^~~
t.cpp:23:3: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
t.cpp:12:3: note: candidate: 'foo::foo(std::initializer_list<int>)'
   12 |   foo(std::initializer_list<int> il = {}): foo{ std::array<int,5>(il) }
      |   ^~~
t.cpp:12:3: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
t.cpp:9:3: note: candidate: 'foo::foo()'
    9 |   foo(): foo{{}}
      |   ^~~
t.cpp:9:3: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
t.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr foo::foo(const foo&)'
    3 | class foo
      |       ^~~
t.cpp:3:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
t.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr foo::foo(foo&&)'
t.cpp:3:7: note:   conversion of argument 1 would be ill-formed:
```

Comment: do you really need the `std::initializer_list` constuctor? Without it you can already create a `foo` via `foo f{{1,2,3,4,5}};`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::array` has no (any) explicitly declared constructors and so, it has no constructor from initializer list, so you cant just forward initializer list to array.
As a workaround, you can use variadic template constructor

```
template <typename ... Args>
foo(Args && ... args) : foo(std::array<int, 5>({args ...}))
```

Comment: Does the RHS of `int a[] = { 1,2,3 };` have a type that is somehow related to `std::initializer_list`?

Comment: @Vroomfondel That uses aggregate initialization. It does not even have a type afaik.

Comment: @Vroomfondel no, this is old syntax for c-like array and struct initialization, that was extended later for all other types

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for this syntax:

```
Foo(const int(&values)[5])
```

Full example,

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{

public:
    Foo(const int(&values)[5])
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(values), std::end(values), std::begin(m_values));
    }

    const auto& values() const noexcept
    {
        return m_values;
    }

private:
    std::array<int, 5> m_values;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo({ 1,2,3,4,5 });

    for (const auto& value : foo.values())
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```